# Adding files to multiple folders in s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I want to upload files which is present in tempFolder to 2 different buckets of s3.My code works as expected to upload multiple files to foldername1. 
tempFolder has 8 files. i have upload all 8 to foldername1 and only last 2 files to my foldername2 in s3.
how can i add them.

```
function foo() {
    let tempFolder = // folder path 
        return fs.readdirSync(tempFolder ).map((file) => {
            let path = path.join(tempFolder , file);
            let awsPath1 = // s3 bucket foldername1
            let awsPath2 = // s3 bucket foldername2
            let total = fs.statSync(path);
            return s3Upload(awsPath1, () => fs.createReadStream(path), total.size)
                .then(
                    () => {
                        s3Uploaded.push("https://aws.amazon.com/s3/bucketname/" + awsPath);
                    });
        });
}
```

Comment: S3 has no real concept of "folders".  Just change your path as needed.

Comment: @Brad Ok then how can i upload files to 2 different paths ?

Comment: It's in your code... `awsPath`... just set it to whatever path you want.  `folder1/file` or `folder2/file`, etc.

Comment: how to add creatreadstream for both and return once both are done

Comment: I don't know what your `s3Upload` is, but if you use the official AWS SDK, it supports promises which would be useful.